# Convert PDF to image in PHP without ImageMagick

Tags: php, linux, image, pdf, imagemagick

I have a PHP site that requires PDF to image conversion, and we're obviously using imagemagick for it. 
However, right now we're trying to move to different hosting, and it seems like I will not be able to install imagemagick package on the new hosting to do the same thing as we do now.

So the question is - is there any way to convert PDF to image with either pure PHP means, or with anything else that can be just popped into DOCUMENT_ROOT and do not need to be properly installed into the system.

This is a Linux system, but I have no idea what distribution, and I can't check as my rights in this system are really limited.

thanks
Alex.

Comment: Please check it. It may help you http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Comment: Rest online PDF to Image service can do that for you http://www.convertapi.com/
No need to install anything on server because all conversions are done on the service cloud pc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *"[...] requires PDF to image conversion, and we're obviously using imagemagick for it."*

This is not obvious at all.

Because **ImageMagick cannot convert PDF** to images all by itself. It requires to use Ghostscript as its *'delegate'*. So you may have installed ImageMagick, but not installed Ghostscript and it will not work.

Vice versa, you could have Ghostscript installed but not ImageMagick -- and you could still easily convert PDF to images. For instance, convert to JPEG with resolution 144 DPI (without specifying one, you'd get 72 DPI):

```
gs              \
  -o out.jpg    \
  -sDEVICE=jpeg \
  -r144         \
   in.pdf
```

Also, you are free to install Ghostscript wherever you want.

<sub>*(**BTW:** I'd keep my hands off a hosting provider who does not offer a ImageMagick nor Ghostscript installation, let alone not allow to install it yourself...)*</sub>

Comment: Hmm, I can't check if the GhostScript really can do it without ImageMagick, as the server I have has it both installed, and I can't touch that - it's production.
However the advice in italics turned out to be most useful - we'll steer away from this gimped hosting for the sake of more expensive but a proper one.

Comment: @user1450663: Ghostscript can do it without ImageMagick. ImageMagick cannot do it without Ghostscript. You can run the `gs` command I gave you in the answer to see the proof. And you can additionally run ImageMagick's command `convert -verbose some.pdf some.png` and you'll see that ImageMagick calls an external Ghostscript executable with various parameters, one of them being `-sDEVICE=pngalpha`.

Answer (score 4):

On linux systems statically linked things can work without external library dependencies. So if you could get/create a statically linked imagemagick executable, you could use it directly under docroot. Probably it isnt so trivial.

Or you could use remote sites for doing the conversion for you. Like:
http://pdf2jpg.net/
(For posting to upload forms like this curl will be usefull.)